# How to automatically redirect to next page after completing reCAPTCHA without "Submit" button?

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

I am trying to redirect the person to a different page after captcha attempt is successful. Basically I want them to be routed to a specific page after clicking "verify" button inside captcha

I used this code, but this is not working.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success")
  {
     function Redirect()
      {
         window.location.href = "example.com";
         }

           setTimeout(Redirect,5000);
            }
             else alert("You can't proceed!");
              </script>

  <div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-callback` to specify a function to be called when the response is successful.

```html
<script>
function captchaPassed() {
    location.href = "example.com";
}
</script>
<div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey" data-callback="captchaPassed"></div>
```

Note that you should still verify the token on the server.